# tf subscriber information?

Tags: ros, tf-tree, learning-tf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working with a complicated ROS system involving a number of nodes and therefore a tf tree. I just wanted to know, is there a command to find out which particular transform or tfs are being subscribed to by a given node.

For example, when I see the rqt_graph, it just shows the node subscribe to /tf and not which tf. Along the same lines, it only shows which nodes are publishing to /tf but not which transform particularly.

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186554/tf-subscriber-information-?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run

```
rosrun tf tf_monitor
```

to see which nodes publish which frames to tf. Alternatively, you can run

```
  rosrun tf view_frames
```

and view the resulting PDF.

There is no generic way to know which frames are used inside a node, however. All nodes with tf TransformListeners receive all messages published on the tf topic, so from a ROS communication layer view there is no way to know.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-14**:
Thank you, that's what I wanted to know. So I guess the go to option to figure that out is to read the source code then.